# Which is correct, "pass" or "pass by": If you ________ a supermarket, could you get me some milk?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is correct, pass or pass by? or both?

If you ________ a supermarket, could you get me some milk?

A. pass
B. pass by

Comment: What do you think? Have you googled them?

Comment: Either works for me.

Comment: Actually, this is an example sentence shown in Cambridge dictionary, and it writes "pass." However, in Longman dictionary, it shows,"Will you be passing by the supermarket on your way home?" That's why I am asking if they are both correct or which one is better.

Comment: They are both correct, and, in my opinion, neither is better.

Comment: If both are used as examples in dictionaries, **obviously** both are correct!

Comment: Carol may not realise that dictionaries sometimes give slightly different definitions.

Comment: "pass by" could mean walk past without going inside, but it can also mean "go near". You should find both "pass" and "pass by" in a good dictionary, such as Collins COBUILD or Merriam-Webster.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these sentences are perfectly valid and there's no difference in meaning. It's purely a matter of personal preference.

> If you **pass** a supermarket, could you get me some milk?
>
> If you **pass by** a supermarket, could you get me some milk?